# cygwin mirror site for 64 bit set up

Tags: windows, operating-system, cygwin

I am trying to install cygwin  setup-x86_64.exe for 64 bit application. But I am not able to find the mirror site to download the cygwin package. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

setup-x86_64.exe is the installer.

Your seems seems a proxy problem:

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-connection